# sql server: a search method like google

Tags: sql-server

I have this scenario :
I have a user table that has two column: Name and family.
what I want is that when user search a keyword ,for example 'name1 family1' ,all the result that have name: name1 and family: family1.
this is only one example and and my scenario is very complicated.(I want search name,lastname in one tables and phone number,address,so on related to current table).:(

is this search like google in an sql database possible? how? can I use fulltextsearch for this? how?

thank you.

Comment: use LIKE syntax for the same

Comment: @HardikVinzava : unfortunately LIKE syntax not work,because for example no record was found with name: 'name1 family1' ...

Comment: Where are you getting the input from? Is it an application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Create a view with schemabinding on your table with two columns: The ID (as PK) and a combined string of all fields you want to include in the full text search.

```
create view [dbo].[View_FamilyData] 
with schemabinding as 
select ID, 
        LastName+' '+FirstName+' '+Phone+' '+Address as SearchText
  from dbo.YourTable
```

Then put a fulltext index on the the column `SearchText`.

Finally, play around with the various possiblities of `CONTAINS`,`FREETEXT`, `CONTAINSTABLE` and `FREETEXTTABLE`.

```
select T.*
  from YourTable T
   join View_FamilyData v
     on v on T.ID = v.ID
  where contains (SearchText,'Smith 12345')
```

Comment: thank you,you save me! but one question what is schemabinding?

Comment: Just look up the answer at TechNet: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/ms187956.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
private void tbautocomplete_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AutoCompleteStringCollection namecollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=88888;Initial Catalog=contrynames;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT  distinct(person_Firstname+''+person_Lastname) AS name FROM persondetails WHERE name Like '%'+@name+'%'";
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader rea = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (rea.HasRows == true)
    {
        while (rea.Read())
        namecollection.Add(rea["name"].ToString());            
    }
    rea.Close();

    tbautocomplete.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
    tbautocomplete.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    tbautocomplete.AutoCompleteCustomSource = namecollection;
```